# Can I create a new stored procedure with error inside?

Tags: sql, sql-server

This morning I try to create an stored procedure in SQL Server and I know there's error inside it but for some reasons I want to keep it and fix it in the future.  But when I execute "create procedure", it returned error told me that something wrong.  And I think because of this, the procedure didn't be created but I want to create this procedure even there's problem.

Any ideas?

Comment: can you post the code so we can see where the error is?

Comment: What is the point of having a stored procedure in SQL Server that will always fail? Store it in source control, for example.

Comment: What is the actual error message?

Comment: I tried to query active directory in this SP and the error is "An error occurred while preparing the query "SELECT *
FROM 'LDAP://hostname/DC=test,DC=local '
where ObjectClass = 'Group'" for execution against OLE DB provider "ADsDSOObject" for linked server "ADSI"."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are getting an error when running the CREATE statement, then you will be unable to create it.  You can save it as a .SQL file and fix the error later.

This is different than an error you might get when running the procedure.  There is something wrong with the create statement syntax wise, or some other issue such as SP of same name, lack of permissions to create SP's, etc.  Either way, you shouldn't be able to CREATE the SP until those problems are fixed.

Answer (score 1):

There's another way.

Instead of **saving** the **.sql File**.

You can **comment the error part** and run the Procedure.

This will store the **Procedure in your DB** and then you can Fix it later.